# TFS project working simultaneously on 2 TFS servers

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

we have 2 dev teams, one team work on TFS2005 and the other team work on TFS2010.
it's the **SAME** project but one team is continue to work on .net framework1.1 project version and the other team work on the .net framework4.0 project version.

WE HAVE ONLY SOURCE CONTROL (NO WORKING ITEMS AND ETC...)

1. after we do the first import from TFS2005 to TFS2010 to TPC X, can we import after one week just the changes of the passed week?
2. can we do import (TFS2005 to TFS2010) to the same TPC X (already existing one) ?
3. can check in can be done automatic to 2 TFS servers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you already have two versions of this project in two separate TFS Servers. I agree with James that it's best not to split codebase across two version control systems, but sometimes we just end up in this type of situation.

How are you importing from TFS2005 to TFS2010?
This is an important question. TFS2010 does not have a way to import a single Team Project from one server to another. You can Import an entire TPC (Team Project Collection). I know of only two methods:
A) Seriously look at TIP (TFS Integration Platform). It's not perfect, but it is designed to do what you are looking for.
B) You can do a snapshot migration. Basically this means getting latest from VS2005, check in to VS2010 (wherever you want), then leave all prior history in VS2005.

If TIP doesn't work for you or is deemed too risky or missing critical info then find out if TFS2010 can import TFS2005 databases to migrate your TFS2005 Team Project Collection. If yes then make a copy of the TFS2005 Version Control databases, then import the entire Team Project Collection into TFS2010, then delete the other TFS2005 projects from this collection that aren't needed. You can call this your TFS2005 Archive Team Project Collection and keep the full fidelity version history on-hand if needed. I did a migration from TFS2008 to TFS2010 a couple times. It's non-trivial but doable.

Migration approaches:
Plan A: Migrate everything to TFS2010 and retire TFS2005 as soon as you can. You can archive 2005 or perhaps move it to a virtual machine if you feel it's essential to have available... but you really want to cut your admin work in half plus get 5 years worth of improvements by moving everything to TFS2010.

Plan B: Set up a system that allows you to integrate between the two servers until you can finally retire TFS2005. Stay in this situation only as long as absolutely necessary and upgrade whatever you need to unblock moving everything to TFS2010.

**Q&A:**

1. After we do the first import from TFS2005 to TFS2010 to TPC X, can we import after one week just the changes of the passed week?
   **A:** It should be doable, but fidelity of import depends on how you are importing. 
   If you are doing a "snapshot migration" by checking in the latest version of VS2005 code into VS2010 then you can check out the first snapshot, repeat a new snapshot over the code, then merge the changes. The **BIG** drawback to snapshot migration process is that you lose all metadata in TFS2005 including change history, labels, checkin comments...
   If you use TFS Integration Platform hopefully most content and metadata will transfer. The neat thing here is once you define the synchronization rules and run it once you can simply re-run the same migration with minor changes. Watch for how labels and changeset metadata gets transferred.
2. Can we do import (TFS2005 to TFS2010) to the same TPC X (already existing one) ?
   TFS Integration 
   **A:** That shouldn't be a problem. TFS Integration Platform or checking in a "snapshot migration" can be targeted to any folder path. I assume there is no formal branch relationship established between the two codebases currently. Therefore I'd strongly recommend checking in the imported files into a separate folder, convert it to a branch (if not already done by import process), then establish whatever branching relationship makes sense to the existing TFS2010 project branch. If there is no shared code between these two projects then I'd keep their branches separated.
3. Can check in can be done automatic to 2 TFS servers? 
   **A:** That's the promise of TIP (the TFS Integration Platform). I personally had a rocky time trying to get it to migrate full source history from one TFS2010 Server to another, but big part of that problem was network issues traveling across 6,000+ miles and 3 firewalls.

   Start by reading this blog and it's comments for a well balanced discussion of TIP and current limitations: [TFS Integration Platform Updated (Mar ‘11)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/03/28/tfs-integration-platform-updated-mar-11.aspx)

   Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid splitting your code base accross 2 servers if possible. Once you've moved the code in to TFS 2010 I'd use branching to distinguish between the .net 1.1 version of the code and the .net 4 version.

Once you have the code in branches you can merge the code on a regular basis to keep the versions in step.

You need to think about what branching stratgy works best for your situation, read the [guidance on codeplax](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) to help you decide. Your branching strategy will depend largly on whether the .net 1.1 version of your code is being actively developed or if it's just in maintenance / bug fix mode.

If you're using VS 2003 to do the .net 1.1 development you can use the [MSSCCI provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6) to give you basic TFS integration.